# Many samples of points in 2 dim space. Test if these points represent a line

Tags: regression

I am not an expert in statistics, and would appreciate your help. Suppose I have several samples (say, years) of points in a 2 dimensional space.

Year 1:
values of variable x, values of variable y

Year 2:
values of variable x, values of variable y

...

Year N:
values of variable x, values of variable y

Every year the number of observations is different. The question that I am trying to answer is: how good is the line approximation for the relationship between variable x and variable y? The different years are assumed to be independent and the lines (slope, intercept) can be different. But how can I determine whether the statement "the relationship between x and y can be represented by a line" is true or not?  If you also give me some R code, I would highly appreciate that.

Thanks!

Comment: To start with it would be helpful bringing the data into a better format: every row representing a single measurement and every column representing a variable being measured. The currently present, more condensed format only makes things cumbersome. From that point on this sounds like a basic regression problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good measure for how well 2D data fit into a line would be the [determination coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). As you are familiar with R, you may want to compare compare:

```r
a=rnorm(100)
b=rnorm(100)
plot(a,b)
cor(a,b)^2
```

With

```r
a=rnorm(100)
b=5*a + 3 + rnorm(100)
plot(a,b)
cor(a,b)^2
```

As a first attempt, I would try to completely forget about the "year" variable, as it doesn't seem relevant for your question. If you want to see whether the determination coefficient evolves with time, and you have a large enough sample to do so in a meaningful way, you can check the different values for each yearly-segregated subgroup of data